# AngularJS/JQuery Unknown Exception: Access is denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have been scratching my head for 3-4 days around this exception we are getting in our application. This is a very frequent exception that never occurred in the past. The issue is our application(AngularJS) runs on production and JS/Client Side exceptions are handled and sent on emails. The issue with this particular exception is we do not know where it is occurring. Usually we get controller name and the line number that threw the exception in stack trace. In this case we are totally unaware and this exception is just not stopping. Has anyone ever encountered such exception or is there a way to find out what is the route cause of this? All we get is the following as exception details:

```
Stack Trace:
Error: Access is denied. at attr (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe79931.js:3:31693) 
at n.access (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe79931.js:2:30155) 
at attr (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe79931.js:3:31531) 
at Xb.prototype.$set (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:73:36) 
at Anonymous function (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:204:2) 
at Anonymous function (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:73:107) 
at s (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:7:300) 
at Xb.prototype.$set (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:73:84) 
at Anonymous function (https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:69:338) 
at Anonymous function https://approvals.mywebsite.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:90:32)
```

**Additional Information:
Browser: Internet Explorer 11
JQuery: 2.1.1
AngularJS: 1.3.7**

Comment: the context is not clear enough to help without seeing the code you have

Comment: As a first step, are you able to include the non-minified versions of AngularJS and jQuery? You could have a look in the libs' code then and maybe figure out what the libraries are trying to do right before the Error occurs.